What "tower pin" is Bugs referring to?
In The Matrix Resurrections (2021), Neo accepts the red pill from Morpheus, and Bugs attaches
a device to Neo’s wrist:

Seq: Keep the loop tight.
Bugs: Cybebe needs that tower pin.
Berg: I got a signal. It’s faint. It’s definitely off-grid.

What "tower pin" is Bugs referring to?
